# what will happen when eden is full but all objects in it is alive

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am learnging Java memory management, From what I already learned from internet.

Minor GC is triggered when Eden space is full, Minor GC will copy objects still being referenced to one survivor space which is empty, but that space is smaller than Eden, What will collector do when eden is full of alive objects ? AFAIK，Java GC Collector is copying collector, it should move all live objects away then clear old memory space.

Comment: The phrase “then clear old memory space” is misleading. The Old generation is not involved and the Eden space and From Survivor space are not cleared but simply considered free, without taking any additional action. And when the survivors do not fit into the To Survivor space, there are two options: 1) change the heap assignments, e.g. make the Young generation bigger or change the Eden/Survivor ratio, or 2) promote objects to the Old generation. Or well, there’s 3) fail when the entire heap is full.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but the problem is that there are hundreds of similar questions about GC already on SO. But it's hard to sort through them all to find the answers.

Comment: @Holger you're right; it just declares that those are old regions.

Comment: @Eugene details may vary, depending on the selected GC algorithm…

Answer (score 1):

> Minor GC is triggered when Eden space is full

*almost* correct. A minor GC can be triggered when a major GC is triggered. It's like the GC says : "I need to do a Full GC, but first I'll do a minor one". In that case (`G1` does this, for example), `Eden space` might not be full.

When that happens (some `Eden` regions could not be completely evacuated), those regions are made old, as even commented [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l4276):

> Regions that failed evacuation are always made old...